# File API: What browsers support the slice method?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

What is the current support for the [`slice`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-slice) method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently Chrome 6+, FF 4+:

- Firefox 3.6+ (*partial* file support, but not `.slice()` yet)
- Firefox 4+ (*full* file support, though I'm unsure which beta this was added in)
- Chrome 6+ (*full* file support)

Of course this list will become outdated, hopefully soon. [There's a test available at html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) for others to test their browser as new releases happen as well.

Comment: Blob `slice` support will be added in Firefox 4 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob

Comment: @YiJiang - I see that it's *supposed* to be added, trying to do a side-by-side install of FF beta now to see if it actually has, if anyone already has it installed there's a test here: http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Yep, works in FF4.0b7: “Your browser appears to support all of the functionality used in this sample” and demo functioned correctly.

Comment: @Nick That's actually the only reference to the `slice` function I could find searching, along with some reference to Chrome 5+ having support for the File API, but I suppose you have much better Google-fu than me

Comment: @YiJiang – I added a link to the spec in the question

Comment: @Marcel, @YiJiang - thanks to both - I just confirmed the same here, answer updated!